# Printing the result of a searching a string in text document. PYTHON

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, search, match

i'm trying to figuring out a problem.
I have a file with a name inside of it, eg: Alex. I want to create a script that is trying to find the specific input and return the results like: "I found: Alex" [image: CODE AND FILE]

Help me please! Thank's a lot !

Comment: Please don't post code as picture, but as text. So others can search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- read the file line by line;
- load words from each line in an array/list;
- loop through the array and compare each item with the with the string you are looking for.

**test3.txt**

```
Alex
Foo 
Bar 
Alex 
Spam
```

**test.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

searching_for = raw_input('Looking for: ')

with open('test3.txt') as file:
  lines = file.read().splitlines()

for i in range(0, len(lines)):
  if(lines[i] == searching_for):
    print 'Found something: ' + lines[i]
```

Comment: Are you a romanian? Because i'm too. If you can, you can come back with a code example. I want to return like " a google sarch"  Thank's!

Comment: Salut, sunt incepator si lucrez la un proiect personal. Din poza de mai sus vreau sa spun ca, daca se poate, ca atunci cand user-ul sa caute sa spunem "Alex Popescu" sa ii apara pe ecran ceva de genul "Am gasit urmatoarele rezultate: Alex Popescu, etc", ca un fel de cautare pe google. Mersi

Comment: This is a rather silly example. It doesn't use regexp as your sample, but it reports the occurrences of the string being searched for. If it's not what you're after, tell us more.

Comment: It sill give me an error:   print ('Found something: ') + lines[i]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: I think it's because you type more than one word. A google-like search would mean indeed typing more than one term. The example above would assume tryping a word and hitting the enter key.

Comment: Nope, i just typed: Alex. and is showing this error

Comment: I just modified this: print ('Am gasit ceva: {}'.format(lines[i])) . Thank you man! You just saved me!